# Does anybody use Jersey in embedded mode(not servlet env but standalone Grizzly instance) successfully with a template engine?

Tags: jersey, velocity, freemarker, grizzly, rythm

Velocity, Freemarker, Japid, Rythm, any other?
What i am looking for is a solution similar to what JSP provides in servlet environment. It should be a form of ViewProcessor implementation, but working on standalone embedded Grizzly deployment(NIO architecture).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jersey has support for freemarker templates - see [jersey-freemarker module](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3a%22jersey-freemarker%22) on maven. It works with any container (i.e. is not depending on servlet). There is also freemarker sample in Jersey workspace that shows how to use it - see [here](http://java.net/projects/jersey/sources/svn/show/trunk/jersey/samples/freemarker).

Answer (score 1):

I think all the template engines you listed could be used in an independent environment. Specifically for Rythm (coz I am the author of this stuff), it loads template files from different sources:

1. from the String content supplied:

   `String result = Rythm.render("hello @who", "world");`
2. from a file found from the `rythm.root` setting:

   `String result = Rythm.render("helloWorld.html", "world");`
3. from a file found from the class path if you have no `rythm.root` setup

It just doesn't depend on any servlet container, so you are free to use it as long as you have JRE. Be sure to set `rythm.noFileWrite` to `true` if you want to use it in GAE where no file write is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The Open Source Project

http://www.bitplan.com/index.php/SimpleRest

supplies a TemplateResource base class which will do most of the "heavy lifting" to make Jersey, Grizzly and the Rythm template engine work together nicely.